# datagridview view hidden columns

Tags: xml, datagridview, dataset

I convert XML to dataset. Looking at the relations I see that relations are created _ID, etc. I want to view these added columns when I connect the dataset to a datagridview to assist in filtering the data. I am wondering if anyone knows if this is possible and how to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to display hierarchical view on a WinForm - DataGridView is not a right choice - it does not support hierarchy.

You need to look for other controls. [Infragistics Grid](http://www.infragistics.com/products/windows-forms/grid/) is one of the choices, there're multiple other ones as well.